# How to switch to register component when login component is on NotAuthorized? Blazor

Tags: blazor, authorize

I am new to Blazor and i need to help. I'm trying to explain what the problem is.

MainLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@attribute [Authorize]
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <NavMenu />
            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
                    <LoginDisplay />
                    <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content px-4">
                    @Body
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <Login />    <----- Redirect to login if an user is not signed
        <Register /> <----- The user should switch to register.razor
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

In Login.razor
I'm trying to add a simple href to /register if an user doesn't have account.

```
 <EditForm Model="loginModel" class="w-100" OnValidSubmit="HandleLogin">
            @if (ShowErrors)
            {
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <p>@Error</p>
                </div>
            }
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email adress</label>
                <InputText Id="email" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="loginModel.Email" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => loginModel.Email)" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <InputText Id="password" type="password" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="loginModel.Password" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => loginModel.Password)" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>
               <a href="/register">Don't have account? Click here</a> <---
                </p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sing in</button>
        </EditForm>
```

When I'm clicking on the href link. This doesn't switch me to register.razor.

Any idea how to solve this?
I'm not allowed to use two components on NotAuthorized or just wrong href link?

Comment: Hi Bzred, we avoid to paste images of code on questions and answers, just the code (or text): [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Wow. It is much better now.

Comment: maybe you could say what happens if you click the register-link. Exceptions or something?